# Verb "to email" in German

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

What is the verb "to email" in German?

> Ich werde ihm eine Email schicken.

How to reformulate it using the verb "to email"?

Searching the dictionary [doesn't seem to help](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/Email), finding "Email" which means "enamel".

Comment: Note that it’s "E-Mail", not "Email" (which is [enamel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you don't want to say *E-Mail schicken/senden* for any reasons – which, however, is most common – you can choose between *mailen* or *emailen*.

According to [Wortschatz der Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/), *mailen* is far more common than *emailen*. The verb is used ~60 times more often, as a noun it's ~20 times more common.

This translation is also listed in [Pons](http://de.pons.eu/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=email&l=deen&in=&lf=en).

Comment: mailen ist gebräuchlich. Auch wenn das eine Unart ist Nomen zu verben ;-)

Comment: Mittlerweile könnten wir eigentlich zum guten alten "schreiben" zurückkehren. *Ich schreibe ihm.* Fertig. Sollte es wichtig sein und in Zweifel stehen, welches Medium benutzt wird, kann man immer noch "einen Brief", "eine Postkarte", "eine Email" usw. hinzusetzen.

Comment: @Ingo: ja, aber die korrekte Schreibweise im Deutschen ist "E-Mail". Wir wollen doch keine mit Schmelzglas überzogenen (Email) Kochtöpfe schreiben ;)

Comment: @Ingo: "Ich schreibe ihm ein Bild." Hmm. Klingt irgendwie merkwürdig. *mailen* ist nicht notwendigerweise eine speziellere Form von *schreiben*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja, wenn du wirklich nur ein Bild sendest, ohne Worte, dann verwende doch "senden" oder "schicken".

Comment: Ich verstehe die Diskussion nicht. Man verwendet ja durchaus auch schreiben. Sehr häufig sogar. Ich habe das Verb zwar nicht explizit in meiner Antwort aufgenommen, aber mein Einleitungssatz deutet schon darauf hin, dass es mit Sicherheit (bessere) Alternativen gibt, als "mailen" zu verwenden.